# Searching for a book series involving time travel and immortality

Tags: story-identification, books, time-travel, immortality

I read it a few years ago.  It was a newer book. I remember the series wasn't completed yet.  It involved a man that gets sent back in time.  He helps a village with some sort of irrigation system (I think).  He makes enemies with a man from the village.  They travel somewhere and eat something that makes them immortal.  Fast forward to modern times you find out everything that happened is connected and I believe his enemy from the village is the one who sent him back.  I remember the plot was complex but at the same time one of those "aha! It makes so much sense now!". The main guy also loses his memory at some point.  And I'm pretty sure there was nano tech once it got back to modern times.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you be more specific about when you read this?  Do you remember what the cover looked like?

Comment: 3-4 years ago.  No clue about cover. I read hundreds of books a year.  I got an urge to reread this one.  And hopefully finish the series.